# How to make docker NOT to use a subnet as a bridge network or add a routing exception

Tags: routing, docker

I have a docker host (CentOs7) where I am running multiple dockerized applications and will be having even more in the future.
The problem that I have an external service which I need to access from the host, which uses an 172.18.100.101 address.

Docker automatically assigns subnets for the bridge networks it creates, 172.18.x, 172.19.x, etc:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.x.x.x        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.17.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-0a7f3df38b5c
172.19.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-636432c82f83
```

The options I see:
1. Tell Docker NOT to use the 172.18.0.0 subnet for the bridges. I don't think this is possible in docker.
2. For each docker container I could start specifying a subnet - but this becomes very problematic, as you need to ensure they don't clash, plus docker-compose.yml files are shared across hosts, so this is a management nightmare.
3. Try to route the required ip (172.18.100.101) differently on the host - while the 172.18.0.0 subnet is still there. I am not sure whether this is possible. I have tried it with adding routes, but no help, probably because it gets added after the 172.18.0.0 rule and not before it.

```
$ sudo route add -host 172.18.100.101 dev eth0
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.x.x.x        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.17.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-0a7f3dfsudo ip route show to match 172.18.198.12038b5c
172.18.100.101  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
172.19.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-636432c82f83
```

Any ideas? I guess the question is how to add an "exception" routing for a select ip (or subnet) and make sure that it is applied before the main rule.

EDIT (2018-06-21):
The issue is not about trying to connect t a service in a Docker container. My problem is that on my network there is a service (on a different server, not owned/controlled by me) with ip 172.18.100.101, but I cannot connect to this service from this host, as on this host Docker automatically assigns the 172.18.0.0 range to a bridge network it creates, so any connection attempts to 172.18.100.101 gets sent to bridge Docker created and not to that external host.

Comment: I know that by adjusting the Metric I could achieve priority between the routing rules, but the problem is that the lowest Metric is the one with highest priority and I don't think I can set a non-zero priority for those bridges created by docker automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The Docker `bridge` network is just one of many options for configuring the networking.  The [Docker network documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/#network-drivers) lists many different network plugins you can use for communications with containers.

If you just need to connect to a service in a Docker container, messing with the network is a bit overkill as you are able to open a service port on the host attached to port in Docker.  Docker calls this "publishing ports" and is used in the `docker run` command with the flag `--publish` or `-p`.  There should be no need to connect to a Docker container directly.

Though, if you do want to connect directly to the container, Docker will certainly let you configure that.

EDIT: I misunderstood the original question was about host routing.

Regarding host routing, Docker does let you change the network ranges it uses.  If you are using `docker` to create your networks, [you can configure the `docker0` interface](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/) to whatever range you want, make sure to pick one not currently in use on your network.

If you use `docker-compose` to create the networks, then you need to configure the network ranges in the `docker-compose.yml` file for that project.

Comment: I am sorry, probably my description wasn't clear. The issue is not about trying to connect a service in a Docker container. My problem is that on my network there is a service (on a different server, not owned/controlled by me) with ip 172.18.100.101, but I cannot connect to this service, as Docker automatically assigns the 172.18.0.0 range to a bridge network it creates.

Comment: ok, now I see the routes with overlapping subnets on `172.18.0.0/255.255.0.0` and understand the issue better.  I have made an edit with some info that might help.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, we use docker-compose, which is why I was hoping to find something better than hardcoding into each project's docker-compose.yml file the network range to be used as with multiple projects deployed on multiple nodes that is a maintenance nightmare (to make sure that they never clash with each other). This is why I was hoping to find a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Routes with larger prefixes (like your `172.18.100.101` host route) will have higher priority than routes with a smaller prefix (like the /16 routes added by docker). So, your initial approach should work. However, unless `172.18.100.101` is directly reachable on `eth0`, you will need to specify a gateway for it as well.

e.g:

`ip route add 172.18.100.101/32 via 10.x.x.x dev eth0`